# Convert an RDD to iterable: PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD which I am creating by loading a text file and preprocessing it. I  dont want to collect it and save it to the disk or memory(entire data) but rather want to pass it to some other function in python which consumes data one after the other is form of iterable.

How is this possible?

```
data =  sc.textFile('file.txt').map(lambda x: some_func(x))

an_iterable = data. ##  what should I do here to make it give me one element at a time?
def model1(an_iterable):
 for i in an_iterable:
  do_that(i)

model(an_iterable)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe what you want is [`toLocalIterator()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.toLocalIterator):

Answer (score -2):

```
data =  sc.textFile('file.txt').map(lambda x: some_func(x))
# you need to call RDD method() then loop
for i in data.collect():
  print i
```

Comment: This code will pull all of the RDD contents to the main memory of the driver, which will fail on any large RDD. The requester asked for an Iterator to stream elements one-at-a-time into the driver's main memory.  The RDD's `.toLocalIterator()` method is correct: not `.collect()`.